# How to create function to add extension to a file?

Tags: python, mkdir

I want to create a method to create a file with a specific extension. Example: I want to create `test` and add the extension `.txt` to it and put the new file in `/home/administrator`.

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime
import glob
import time

class Item:
    def __init__(self, nom, path, date):
        self.nom = nom
        self.path = path
        self.date = date

class Dossier:

    def AjouterExtension(self, nom, extension):
        """classe qui va ajouter une extension a un fichier"""
        path = "/home/administrator"
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)

        filename = nom + extension
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb') as temp_file:
            temp_file.write()

mon_doc = Dossier()
mon_doc.AjouterExtension("test", "txt")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    mon_doc.AjouterExtension("test2", "txt")
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 33, in AjouterExtension
    filename = '.'.join(nom, extension)
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Your solution update to my code :

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime
import glob
import time


class Item:
    def __init__(self, nom, path, date):
        self.nom = nom
        self.path = path
        self.date = date









class Dossier:




        def AjouterExtension(self, nom, extension):
            """classe qui va ajouter une extension a un fichier"""
            path = "/home/administrator"
            if not os.path.exists(path):
                os.makedirs(path)

            filename = '.'.join(nom, extension)
            name = "{}.{}".format(filename, extension.lstrip("."))
            with open(path, "w") as fh:
                pass  # or work with fh to add some content


mon_doc = Dossier()
mon_doc.AjouterExtension("test2", "txt")
```

Comment: this looks ok - what doesn't it do that it should be doing?

Comment: /home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/venv/bin/python /home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    mon_doc.AjouterExtension("test", "txt")
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 35, in AjouterExtension
    temp_file.write()
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You're going to want to add a dot between the name and the extension.  What do you plan to write to the file?  You're not writing anything now, as the error says.  `filename = f"{nom}.{extension}"` or `filename = '.'.join(nom,extension)`

Comment: you can use `pass` to have a "do nothing" action instead of `.write()`, which will create an empty file (just open and close the file, creating it per `w` arg to open)

Comment: Or you can just write an empty string: `temp_file.write('')`

Answer (score 1):

When you create the file, add a `.` for your file extension (thanks to [**@Tim Roberts**' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271559/python-linux-how-to-create-function-add-extensions-to-a-file/67271651#comment118907454_67271559))

```py
name = "{}.{}".format(filename, extension.lstrip("."))
```

You can also create a blank file as just

```py
with open(path, "w") as fh:
    pass  # or work with fh to add some content
```

Working with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is also very pleasant and may help with unusual pathing requirements

Comment: i have the error : /home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/venv/bin/python /home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    mon_doc.AjouterExtension("test", "txt")
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 33, in AjouterExtension
    filename = '.'.join(nom, extension)
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: If you want to use `.join()` instead of `.format()`, `.join()` is expecting an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), so you can (or rather must) pack the values into a list or tuple `".".join((nom, extention))`

Comment: It's quite optional, but calling `.lstrip(".")` before adding a new period may help some inputs (as users of your method then won't need to worry if they should or shouldn't prefix the extension with ".") such as ".txt" or "txt"

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    mon_doc.AjouterExtension("test2", "txt")
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 33, in AjouterExtension
    filename = '.'.join(nom, extension)
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: I would recommend using `.format()` instead of `.join()`, but the args must be `j((a,b))`, not `j(a,b)` if you use it; this is creating a tuple `(a,b)` and passing it to `.join()` "exactly one argument" is the _tuple_